# Pause mpmovieplayercontroller programmatically - is it possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Pause mpmovieplayercontroller programmatically - is it possible?

tnx.

Answer (score 6):

MPMoviePlayerController implements the [MPMediaPlayback](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback) protocol, so on your player, you can just send a pause message:

```
[player pause];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:....
...

- (IBAction)btPausePressed {
    [player pause];  
}
```

for me at ios 5.1 it is working

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Apple Documentation of MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW1) you simply need to call `stop` on your object. However, this will also hide it.